# DataStax Devcenter CQL3 version vs Cassandra vrs

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Within DevCenter, I'm getting an error: [feature] is introduced in CQL 3.1.0, you're running CQL 3.0.5.

This doesn't make sense as I'm using the absolute latest version of Cassandra (2.0.6); connecting through cqlsh shows it's using 3.1.1:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
```

What can I do to make DevCenter understand it should be connecting using 3.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

From Alex Popescu alexp@datastax.com on the mailing list:

> DevCenter 1.0 is the Java driver 1.0 to connect to your cluster. This
>   version of the driver doesn't support C* 2.0 with its latest CQL
>   version.  Now you'll still be able to connect to a C* 2.0 cluster, but
>   your queries will actually need to be compatible with C* 1.2
>   (basically none of the new CQL features will work).
>
> On the bright side, we're working on updating DevCenter to use the
>   Java driver 2.0 which supports both C* 1.2 and 2.0 (and their
>   corresponding CQL versions).